# Is it possible to track passive events with Firebase not initiated by a user session on the client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to track my application's revenue with Firebase Analytics. The nature of the revenue events are extremely different to how revenue is generally generated in an e-commerce environment.

*EDIT I guess I should be more specific. I need to track revenue events for users that are independent of application usage, or any particular direct user action. Short of using another analytics platform that supports REST events, I think i may be out of luck.

The obvious solution would be to use google measurement protocol from the backend when these event occur, but it looks like Firebase does not support this API.

Other than that, the only creative alternative I can think of is sending silent pushes to the device in order to trigger the even client side. This is obviously suboptimal and will most definitely not end up being accurate.

Is there another creative workaround i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can send custom events since all the automatically collected Firebase events operate when the app is in foreground. Your custom events would be logged when the app is in the background (as I suppose with your requirements). Please note that, this won't be accounted as session or engagement time events in the reports.

Unless you are not tracking PII and the app's tracking mechanism complies with that of Legal polices, everything is OK.

Comment: I guess this is my only option, it's just really not ideal and is never going to be close to accurate because it depends on the device receiving in the first place. I'm just the unfortunate edge case, as revenue collection doesn't follow 99% of the market

Answer (score 0):

As long as your app is running you should be able to trigger the event regardless of user interaction, no? You could probably bundle all the data you need in the event parameters.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I need to track revenue generated by a particular user. When that revenue event occurs it is not related to when the user opens the application. Therefore the only creative options i can come up with is polling the back end for these events, and then firing these events on the client, or send a silent push, hoping the user has enabled such capability. What i wish i had was a REST api that the server could notify firebase of this revenue event.